# How to let gradle find dependencies from ~/.ivy2/local

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I published some custom jars into `~/.ivy2/local`(using a scala building tool: SBT)

I want to use it in another gradle project, and added the dependency:

```
compiile("com.my:custom_jar_2.11:0.1")
```

but gradle can't find it when I run `gradle test`:

```
Could not find com.my:custom_jar_2.11:0.1
```

I thought gradle would use `~/.ivy/local2` by default, but seems not.

Do I need to configure something(without hardcode absolute path)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you specified a repository entry for your local repo?

```
repositories {
    ivy {
        // URL can refer to a local directory
        url "../local-repo"
    }
}
```

All available in the tutorial. 
http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html